# Open CSS Tab by default using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs

I'm building CSS tabs but need to be able to add a snippet of JS after the code to select a particular tab by default once the page loads.

My code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/kyromedia/C9Xyk/

For example, something like:
Onload > make tab with class "tab-content-3" active

Right now the tab is selected with "checked" like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="pcss3t" checked id="tab1" class="tab-content-first">
```

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/jGsCV/